# Pull data from Excel online spreadsheet for use on a web page

Tags: excel, office365, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to pull data from an Office 365 Excel online sheet for use on a web page.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a Microsoft version of the Google Sheets API: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js - unfortunately I'm not able to use Google sheets due to the project being located in China (where Google services are blocked).

Does anyone know if this exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Mic.rosoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) and probably more suitable to your needs [Excel Rest API](https://dev.office.com/excel/rest)

Comment: Amazing thank you, I'll have a look at both of these.